# How correctly make constraints between view with intrinsic content size?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I have two `UILabel`(vertical direction) in `UIView` and `UIButton` in one "row". I need to get this result:
[image]

Views init code:

```
private lazy var contentView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return view
  }()

  private lazy var priceView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

    return view
  }()

  private lazy var priceLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return label
  }()

  private lazy var oldPriceLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    return label
  }()

  private lazy var callButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(frame: .zero)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 22.0
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("Call", for: .normal)
    button.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    button.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

    return button
  }()
```

Using SnapKit I make constraints:

```
self.contentView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
  make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
  make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(16.0)
  make.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-16.0)
}
  self.priceView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.centerY.left.equalToSuperview()
    make.right.equalTo(self.callButton.snp.left)

  }
  self.priceLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.left.equalToSuperview()
    make.top.equalToSuperview()
    make.right.lessThanOrEqualToSuperview()
  }

  self.oldPriceLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.left.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    make.top.equalTo(self.priceLabel.snp.bottom).offset(8.0)
    make.right.lessThanOrEqualToSuperview()
  })
  self.callButton.snp.makeConstraints { make in
   make.left.equalTo(self.priceView.snp.right)
    make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
    make.height.equalTo(44.0)
    make.right.equalToSuperview()

  }
```

I want `priceView` to shrink to the size of the UILabels and `callButton` stretch on all free space. Hugging and compression not working and I don't understand why.

Now:
[image]

Comment: Constraints are depends on how you wanted to see same UI in diff size devices. Please update question.

Comment: size doesn't matter. The height is fixed. If the width changes, the button will get all the free space.

Comment: See my answer, @AleksandrMaybach

Comment: Do you want either your labels or your button to have a fixed width? For example, if your "prices" are `500` and `600`, the button will be much wider than if your prices are `500 000 000` and `999 999 999 999`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a `UIStackView`, you can correct your issue easily...

For each label, change:

```
make.right.lessThanOrEqualToSuperview()
```

to:

```
make.right.equalToSuperview()
```

and that should fix it.

Comment: Yes, I've used this. It works, but why??? if I have two right = right condition, why autolayout system used biggest.

Comment: By default, the horizontal content hugging priority for a `UILabel` is **Low** (250), and content compression resistance is **High** (750). So, each label will expand to fit its text ***AND*** expand to stick to the right-edge of its superview (with those constraints).

Answer (score 1):

First off, you don't have to set `translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false in each of your views, since you're setting their constraints using **SnapKit**.

Next, the best way to deal with what you want is to utilize the purpose of `UIStackView`.

It's easy as this:

```
self.view.addSubview(self.stackView_Main)
self.stackView_Main.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.height.equalTo(44.0)
    make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(16.0)
    make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(100.0)
}

self.callButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
}
```

And you'll get this perfectly, no warnings:

[image]

Full example code:

```
import SnapKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var stackView_Main: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [self.stackView_Price, self.callButton])
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.spacing = 5.0
        stackView.alignment = .leading
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        return stackView
    }()

    private lazy var stackView_Price: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [self.priceLabel, self.oldPriceLabel])
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 5.0
        return stackView
    }()

    private lazy var priceLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.text = "500 000 000"
        return label
    }()

    private lazy var oldPriceLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.text = "999 999 999 999"
        return label
    }()

    private lazy var callButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: .zero)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 22.0
        button.backgroundColor = .black
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("Call", for: .normal)
        button.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        button.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.view.addSubview(self.stackView_Main)
        self.stackView_Main.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.height.equalTo(44.0)
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(16.0)
            make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(100.0)
        }

        self.callButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
    }


}
```

Let me know if this helps ;)

Comment: I was thinking about  `UIStackView` and your answer is very useful, but feasible to do this without `UIStackView`?

Comment: Yes, it should be, but I'm thinking you need to give your one of the sides a constant width, otherwise you might see some warnings in your logs, and you don't always want that. :)